# my responsive navigation bar doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a responsive menu with bootstrap 3 .so it is working on desktop, but it doesn't work on mobile.

This is my code

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inveren navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: rgb(192, 12, 26) !important;">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="top_menu"><a style="color: whitesmoke; font-family: 'myfont';" href="/Pages/Contact.aspx">تماس با ما</a></li>
                        <li class="top_menu"><a style="color: whitesmoke; font-family: 'myfont';" href="/Pages/Items.aspx">شرایط و راهنما</a></li>
                        <li class="top_menu"><a style="color: whitesmoke; font-family: 'myfont';" href="/Pages/About.aspx">درباره ما</a></li>
                        <li class="top_menu"><a style="color: whitesmoke; font-family: 'myfont';" href="/login/Login.aspx">ورود به حساب کاربری</a></li>
                        <li class="top_menu"><a style="color: whitesmoke; font-family: 'myfont';" href="/Pages/MySangyar.aspx">سنگیار من</a></li>
                        <li class="top_menu"><a style="color: whitesmoke; font-family: 'myfont';" href="../default.aspx">صفحه نخست</a></li>
                        <li class="top_menu">
                            <a title="خروج از پنل کاربری" class="navbar-brand" href="/Default.aspx">
                                <img style="width: 60px; height: 40px;" class="img-responsive img-circle" src="/Images/logo.png" alt="عکسی وجود ندارد" />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

on the desktop full screen : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHeby.png)

and on the desktop when it's in the size of 700 px : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63oOG.png)

and When I load on the Galaxy S5, it loads like the first picture while I want to display like the second picture.

please help me...

thank's so much

Comment: did You change CSS? if not, check answer from Shahidul because maybe You forgot to add this meta viewport ... and this is not related but didn't You want "navbar-inverse" class , You got "navbar-inveren"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add this `meta` tag inside `head` tag of your code:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```